# What art style does this black and white work represent?

Tags: style-identification

My cousin makes this kind of black and white art. He doesn't have any education in art or doing paintings or drawings. He once told me he just sits and draws whatever that comes from within. So, all he makes is really original without any copying. There are some [samples on his page](https://www.facebook.com/Melting-Hallucinations-1601666420072585/):

[image]

I was wondering if this is any known style of art?

Comment: I made some minor changes and included a sample image so users aren't forced to go to FB to see an example.

Comment: @CreationEdge That may or may not have been made by a computer, but I think it is definitely possible to make it by pen and ink, therefore it shouldn't be offtopic here, IMO.

Comment: @TheIndependent It's been reopened since the editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think that this is **high contrast art**. The variance of dark and light colours is very high in that picture. While this does not fit all the styles linked it fits enough of them.

This is like what you see in the classic Che Guevara graphic.

[image]

This effect is not limited to just black and white but excels in using minimal colours.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was good guidance to know that these are high contrast type. How about the the form of it? The Che Guevara piece has an obvious form i.e. it is face of a human. But, the ones my cousin makes doesn't look to follow a strict shape or form. Is there a category or style from that aspect?

Comment: While the Che is facial the art form is not specific to figures like that. It is merely the presence of high contrast colours. from the looks of some of the picture they are trying to represent figures anyway. I suppose you could consider a sub genre of this as abstract high contrast art?

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt for your insights. This was definitely very helpful. I should go back and tell my little cousin this information now so he becomes happy to know there is a name for what he does. I really appreciate it.

Comment: There might be other names for this as well. Don't forget to check if there are other answers!

Answer (score 3):

These are very similar to notan drawings. Artists use notan drawings to quickly determine whether or not their finished painting will have an interesting pattern of dark and light values. It is a valuable tool for establishing an interesting composition in a painting. Arthur Wesley Dow wrote about notan in the 19th century. His book is out of copyright available for free download from the Internet. Notan originated in Japanese art.

Comment: His book, Composition, is an excellent addition to any visual artist's library.

Answer (score 1):

Matt correctly identifies the *style* as *High Contrast Art*. But following the tag [technique-identification](/questions/tagged/technique-identification) - The *technique* frequently used to create this kind of art is [Linocut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linocut).

Comment: The post was very likely mistagged, as the [style-identification]  tag is relatively new. It has been changed since your answer.